# Identifying object by its memory address when debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, memory-address

```
Failed to set (layer.cornerRadius) user defined inspected property on (NSLayoutConstraint): [<NSLayoutConstraint 0x7fe8e945a8d0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key layer.
```

I believe this is because I accidentally set a User Defined Runtime Attribute in Interface Builder, for a constraint. Given I have hundreds of constraints, I don't want to go through each one to find the one giving me this error.

I've tried including an exception breakpoint and viewing "Memory" (Debug -> Debug Workflow -> View Memory).

How can I find which constraint is giving me an issue given the memory address above?

Comment: I went through each constraint one by one, and still couldn't find the error. Any assistance?